# asp.net authentication on nokia e5-00

Tags: .net, asp.net, authentication, mobile, nokia

I am tring to login using asp.net authentication in nokia e5-00 device. The login proccess success under explorer, firefox, android device and so on. But in the nokia device the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is false even though the authentication succeeded.
Here is my login method:

```
public static void Login(User user)
        {
            HttpResponse Response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
            HttpRequest Request = HttpContext.Current.Request;

            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                user.Id.ToString(), DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(12), true,
                user.Id.ToString());

            string data = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, data);
            cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;

            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

            string redirectUrl = UserPages.Home;
            Response.Redirect(redirectUrl, false);
        }
```

Later, in the aspx page, when I try to get the user, `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is still false.

But in all other browsers IsAuthenticated is true and everything is fine.

This behavior happens in all nokia devices. After checking, I see the the cookie stored in the nokia but IsAuthenticated is still false.

What can cause to this problem? What is wrong with the nokia devices??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really knows what was the problem, but this is how I solved it:

Instead the use of my `public static void Login(User user)` I used:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(user.Id.ToString(), true);
```

Again, I am not sure what is the difference or why does this work while my original method doesn't.

If anyone has an answer, I'll be glad to know.

Thanks.